A huge cottonwood tree limb fell on my house
The big limb had smaller limbs coming off of it. One of the smaller limbs went through my roof, all the way through my bedroom ceiling. I fixed the roof, so it doesn't leak. Now I have to fix the little hole in my bedroom ceiling & somehow push the plywood back up & put some beams across my ceiling to fix it & make it look good. My question is can I use a jack & a board to jack up the place where the limb came through to push my ceiling back up to fix it with some beams or 2×4's or whatever size you think is best. I have a bunch of lumber & everything to fix it. I just need a little guidance for the easiest, best way to fix it. I'm a 58 year old woman, fixing it by myself. Thank you in advance

Please add some photos

that sounds like a plan.  the details of how your house is constructed and what parts are broken are missing so it's hard to comment

You have plywood in your ceiling?

You need to get up above the ceiling to see what damage there is. If thinking you need a jack and board, makes it sound like there might be structural damage, rafters or trusses broken. Might also it just popped the drywall off, but a limb large enough to go though the roof and ceiling probably caused structural damage also, making repairs maybe more than DIY.

If there are repairs needed to beams in your ceiling, I would strongly encourage you consult a structural engineer to make sure the integrity of your roof has not been compromised.

Thank you all, so much! I guess the first time I posted my "thank you" it didn't post. I still have to fix my bedroom ceiling and thanks to yall, I know how now and can do it myself

How do I post a picture?
